# Clockwise angle in 3D subspace of $n$-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

Consider a triplet of $n$-dimensional ($n > 3$) vectors: $a$, $b$, $c$.
Their linear span $span(a, b, c)$ forms a 3-dimensional subspace.

As far as I can judge such a fact is invariant of the coordinate system chosen: looking from the end of vector $c$ calculate the clockwise angle from $a$ to $b$ (with respect *only* to vector $c$ in this 3D-subspace).

How can this be done with the $n$-dimensional coordinates given?

Comment: Maybe the first step could be to project all vectors into this 3-dimensional space and to consider all vectors only in this space.

Comment: @Widawensen yes, I've done this. But (e.g., using Gram-Schmidt process) you still can't  use cross product as you have no criterion of the orientation

Comment: Using dot products of $n$-vectors you can find the cosine of the angle you wanted to find, but you can't distinguish clockwise orientation.

Comment: @Somos I'd like to use the vector $c$ to distinguish the direction of the angle

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov I know that you would like to do that, but it is not possible with the information given.

Comment: @Somos could you clarify why? in our 3d space it's quiet possible

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov Actually, no. See the answer by Berci and his comment about 2 vectors in 3D. With just two vectors in 3D you have two possible orientations.

Answer (score 2):

Orientation can only be given for $n$ vectors in $n$ dimension, by the *sign of their determinant*.

It has the important property that when moving the $n$ vectors continuously, such that in every moment they are still linearly independent, the orientation remains the same.

In $n+1$ dimension it becomes ambiguous: any $a_1,\dots, a_n$ linearly independent vectors can be smoothly transformed to any other $b_1,\dots, b_n$ linearly independent vectors. 
For illustration, consider  $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. Using the the $3$rd dimension, we can swap these vectors by a continuous move.

---

Nevertheless, if we relax the orientation question, we can get the angle $\vartheta$ of two vectors $a, b\in\Bbb R^n$ without need of a 3rd vector, by the usual formula 
$$\cos\vartheta =\frac{\langle a, b\rangle}{\Vert a\Vert\cdot\Vert b\Vert} $$
where $\langle a, b\rangle=\sum_ia_ib_i$ and $\Vert x\Vert=\sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle} $.

Comment: however the property mentioned in the question seems to have nothing in common with $n$-dimensional orientation

Comment: Hmm. Indeed, the question is more specific. However, I think, the answer is the same: we can't define it: think about 2 vectors in 3d.

Comment: but I have the _3rd_ vector

Comment: Yes, and a 4th dimension. You can flip the 3rd vector while keeping the other 2 fixed. Their orientation should remain throughout.

Comment: but the subspace is 3-dimensional, it has no difference from ordinary  3d space. I claim this is a geometrical relationship, not coordinates-based. Isn't it?

Comment: What's your definition for this relation?  Seeing clockwise or anticlockwise becomes unclear if we add a dimension.

Comment: I agree, but we do not add a dimension - we're working in 3D embedded space and try to distinguish in this subspace

Comment: Ahh.. The 3d subspace is considered fixed? Then just extend $a, b, c$ to a basis $a, b, c, e_1,e_2,\dots$.

Comment: stil can't understand how knowledge of the $n$D basis orientation helps to learn the orientation in 3D subspace

Comment: Sorry, I was concentrating on the orientation part of your question, and realized just now that primarily you asked about the angle and not just its sign. The sign remains ambiguous unless you fix $n-2$ vectors in place of the unique $c$, however the absolute value of the angle can be determined.

Comment: the cosine distance may be definitely computed. However I don't think the sign of the angle in _3D subspace_ is ambiguous – this subspace is perfectly the same as $\mathbb{R}^3$! The clockwise angle in this setting seems to be independent from the basis orientation etc

Comment: In 2d, sign is determined. In 3d you need one reference vector $c$ to determine the sign, *relatively* to $c$. In 4d you need 2 reference vectors, in $n$d you need $n-2$.

Comment: Once a 3d subspace is fixed, and it's given *with orientation* (which is equivalent to fixing $n-3$ reference vectors that together with the subspace generates the whole space), *then* the sign indeed can be determined, relative to $c$.

Comment: I totally agree with your latest comment but I still can't understand how this should be calculated explicitly

Comment: Suppose $v_1,\dots, v_{n-3}$ are fixed reference vectors, then it's the sign of the determinant of $(a, b, c, v_1,\dots, v_{n-3}) $.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice unified way to establish a direction of an angle. Certainly it has nothing in common with CW/CCW orientation but in practice it has the same sense. If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it as a correct one